# Argument altering messing up code

Tags: arrays, ruby, immutability

The initial method's arguments `rec1` and `rec2` are altered when the second method is called, and `fourpoints` (an array of the two corners of a rectangle) is unexpectedly changed.

```
def rec_inter(rec1, rec2)
  foursides1 = []
  foursides2 = []
  fourpoints = rec1 + rec2
  p fourpoints
  points(rec1, foursides1)
  points(rec2, foursides2)
  crossing = foursides1 & foursides2
  # want to  do -> crossing & fourpoints <- to get intersections 
  p crossing
  p fourpoints #changes due to points method, how do I fix
end
def points(corners, rec)
  while corners[0][0] <= corners[1][0]
    rec << [corners[0][0], corners[0][1]]
    corners[0][0] = (corners[0][0] + 1)
  end
  while corners[0][1] <= corners[1][1]
    rec << [corners[1][0], corners[1][1]]
    corners[0][1] = (corners[1][0] + 1)
  end
  first = rec.flatten[0]
  while corners[1][0] >= first
    rec << [corners[1][0], corners[1][1]]
    corners[1][0] = corners[1][0] - 1
  end
  rec.uniq!
end

#rec1 & rec2 == cross refernce
rec_inter([[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [3, 1]])
```

Is there any way to store these values to a variable that isn't altered when the code is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `fourpoints` array is getting changed is because `rec1` and `rec2` are two-dimensional arrays which means ruby won't copy the arrays within the array.

This can be seen by the following:

```
pry(main)> ary = [[1,2]]
=> [[1, 2]]
pry(main)> ary2 = [[3,4]]
=> [[3, 4]]
pry(main)> f = ary + ary2
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
pry(main)> ary[0][0] = 10
=> 10
pry(main)> f
=> [[10, 2], [3, 4]]
```

In order to fix this problem you need to deep copy the arrays

```
fourpoints = []
rec1.each { |a| fourpoints << a.dup }
rec2.each { |a| fourpoints << a.dup }
```

Then you'll be able to modify `rec1` and `rec2` and not affect `fourpoints`.

Another way to deep copying the arrays is by using `Marshal::load` and `Marshal::dump`

```
fourpoints = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(rec1)) + Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(rec2))
```